# Use Importrange formula with conditioning for date wherein previous date from today will populate the columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to figure out a formula that will use Importrange to populate the Importrange spreadsheet coming from the Original File. The conditions are:

- Rows that are not Paid (Column G) - left blank if not yet paid
- Previous days from today's date (presuming today's date is June 3, 2023) in Column K "Due date reminder"

These two conditions should be met to populate the Importrange spreadsheet.

[image: Original File]

[image: Importrange File]

I have tried two formulas:

1. Using if-and-importrange formulas:
   `=(if(And(IMPORTRANGE("url_Original_File","June 2023!**J2**")<$J$5,IMPORTRANGE("url_Original_File","June 2023!**G2**")="Paid"),"False",IMPORTRANGE("url_Original_File","June 2023!**B2**")))`

Problem with this is that when I dragged down this formula to another cell, the boldened cell number don't dragged down. Example, J2, G2, & B2, should changed to J3, G3, & B3 if I dragged down the formula.

2. Query function:
   `=query(IMPORTRANGE("url_Original_File"","June 2023!B2:O500"),"select B, where K < date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("6/3/2023"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`

I have an **Error message** that says "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter2:

`PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "where" "where "" at line 1, column 11. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null" ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second" ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ... <ID> ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ..."`

I am expecting that on the importrange file, it will autopopulate data from Original File those rows or accounts that are overdue or accounts that did not pay on the due date.